# Pandoc cannot fetch from network drive

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

I'm trying to knit a R Markdown but for some reasons its not able to fetch the css from the network drive

Is there a way to fix this ?

The error is as under:

```
Could not fetch http://hq-fs-02/users$/D/Documents/R/R-3.5.1/library/rmarkdown/rmd/h/highlightjs/default.css
HttpExceptionRequest Request {
  host                 = "hq-fs-02"
  port                 = 80
  secure               = False
  requestHeaders       = []
  path                 = "/users$/D/Documents/R/R-3.5.1/library/rmarkdown/rmd/h/highlightjs/default.css"
  queryString          = ""
  method               = "GET"
  proxy                = Nothing
  rawBody              = False
  redirectCount        = 10
  responseTimeout      = ResponseTimeoutDefault
  requestVersion       = HTTP/1.1
}
 (ConnectionFailure Network.Socket.connect: <socket: 700>: failed (Connection refused (WSAECONNREFUSED)))
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 61
Execution halted
```

Answer (score 2):

I've been having the same problem trying to insert an image into a markdown presentation, where the image is hosted on a network drive. My solution was to to insert and R code chunk and connect to the image in R and essentially print it into the markdown. Basically cutting pandoc out of the equation.

```
library(magick)
image_read("//server/file.jpg")
```